# An intuitive explanation of the basis-independency of EPR pair

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

As usual, we write the EPR pair as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\left|00\right> + \left|11\right>).
$$

A property of the EPR pair is that this definition is *basis-independent*, which means
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\left|00\right> + \left|11\right>) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\left|uu\right> + \left|vv\right>)
$$
as long as $\left|u\right>$ and $\left|v\right>$ are orthogonal in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (As pointed out by @ElioFabri, if we set $\left|u\right>=\left|0\right>$ and $\left|v\right>=i\left|1\right>$ then the equailty no longer holds. Hence we cannot put them in $\mathbb{C}^2$.)

> Question: Is there any way to explain this other than an elementary direct computation?

Comment: *A property of the EPR pair is that this definition is
basis-independent* I can't see it's true. If $|u\rangle=|0\rangle$ and
$|v\rangle=i\,|1\rangle$ your identity doesn't hold.

Comment: @ElioFabri I think we need orthogonal basis.

Comment: *I think we need orthogonal basis*. Sure. But
$\{|0\rangle, i\,|1\rangle\}$ *is* orthogonal.

Comment: @ElioFabri You are right. I've modified the OP.

Comment: *as long as $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$ are orthogonal in R2*. 
I'm not sure how to interpret that. Do you mean that a real Hilbert
space should be used? I would suggest the following. Starting from a base $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$, in order to keep the EPR pair invariant you may only use new bases obtained from the former through a *real orthogonal* matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat way to see this.

The main element is vectorization. Vectorization of a matrix $A=\sum A_{i,j}\vert i \rangle\langle j\vert$ is defined by $\vert\text{vec}({A})\rangle = \sum A_{i,j}\vert i \rangle\vert j\rangle$. Essentially, a bra turns into a ket. The cute thing about this is that you've now established a correspondence between matrices and bipartite pure states.

Next, consider what the identity matrix vectorizes to. You have $\sum_i \vert i \rangle\langle i\vert \rightarrow \sum_i \vert i \rangle\vert i\rangle $, which is an unnormalized Bell state. Indeed, if you chose to do it in two dimensions and the computational basis, you have your state $\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert + \vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert \rightarrow \vert\Phi^+\rangle = \vert 00 \rangle + \vert 11\rangle$ upto normalization. You might be interested in the other Pauli matrices and what they do. I leave it to you to work it out but they simply give you the other Bell states.

But wait, you're free to write the identity as $\sum_i\vert i \rangle\langle i\vert$ in any orthonormal basis. So indeed you can have $i = \{0,1\}$ or $i = \{+,-\}$ or as you wanted to write it, $i = \{u,v\}$ for some $\vert u\rangle \perp \vert v\rangle$.

In some sense, the intuition is that because the identity matrix vectorizes to the $\vert\phi^+\rangle$ state, the freedom in representing the identity using any orthonormal basis carries over to the freedom in representing the vectorized state.

Comment: Elegant! I think there’s only one (maybe trivial) thing I cannot see through. That is, it is not obvious to me that the vectorization is base-independent. Would you please give me some hints?

Comment: I'm not sure if that statement is true. What I can tell you is that there is a vectorization identity $A\otimes B^T\vert\text{vec}(X)\rangle = \vert\text{vec}(AXB)\rangle$. What you are doing when you go from $\vert 00\rangle + \vert 11\rangle$ to $\vert uu\rangle + \vert vv\rangle$ is to apply the unitary $U\otimes U^*$ (note the conjugate!) on $\vert\text{vec}(I)\rangle$. But when you apply the vectorization identity, you get $\vert\text{vec}(UIU^\dagger)\rangle = \vert\text{vec}(I)\rangle$. I'm not sure if there's a more general argument.

Comment: @nr2618 *I'm not sure if that statement is true.* It can't as
vectorization isn't a linear map, turning a bra into a ket.